# Scrollable Fragment like Google StreetView

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to be able to implement a fragment that is scrollable from the bottom of the screen like what is found on the Google StreetView app.

Do i need a custom view or it is in a support library. I have tried using scroll and PercentageView and being unable to achieve similar behaivour as found on Google StreetView App.

Answer (score 0):

Before few weeks I have used [this](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel). 
The layout must have only two childrens, the first one is the main layout and the second one is for sliding up.

Also if you want to add tabs (like in Google street view) set TabLayout as second child. Then for the tabs' names set transparent background on the Toolbar to achieve the GoogleStreeView transparent effect.

In my case the first child(main layout) is a fragment, the second one is a relative layout. You can set what you want.

Hope this helps. :)